# drag or drop folder using keyboard on windows 11

Tags: windows, drag-and-drop

I am using the Windows 11 Operating System. I searched and I could not find a way. I wonder if we can drag or drop a folder using the keyboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you don't mind, just use Ctrl-C/V to complete the folder move.
2. You can try the **Mouse Keys** function provided by Microsoft self. Using it you can control the mouse pointer with the numeric keypad on your keyboard, and therefore complete the folder drag and drop.

- How to enable **Mouse Keys**?

  See "Control your mouse with a numeric keypad" in this [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/make-your-mouse-keyboard-and-other-input-devices-easier-to-use-10733da7-fa82-88be-0672-f123d4b3dcfe#WindowsVersion=Windows_11).
- How to **drag and drop** after enabling **Mouse keys**.

  See this [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/use-mouse-keys-to-move-the-mouse-pointer-9e0c72c8-b882-7918-8e7b-391fd62adf33) for the key mappings.

  First, move your mouse pointer to the target folder by pressing 1-4 and 6-9. Then press key "0" once which will select the folder and keep the state. After that, you can freely move it to the target position by pressing 1-4 and 6-9. Finally, press key "." (or "5") once to drop the folder.

Comment: The instruction is clear, thank you.